# Importing External PHP class into Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use **phpspellcheck** in my Laravel application and I put it inside the app folder and I include it inside my code like this :

```
  include(app_path() .'/phpspellcheck/include.php');

        $mySpell = new SpellCheckButton();
        $mySpell->InstallationPath = "/phpspellcheck/";
        $mySpell->Fields = "ALL";
        echo $mySpell->SpellImageButton();

        $mySpell = new SpellAsYouType();
        $mySpell->InstallationPath = "/phpspellcheck/";
        $mySpell->Fields = "ALL";
        echo $mySpell->Activate();
```

But now I receive an error like this :

```
"Class 'App\SpellCheckButton' not found"
```

I have these files inside the include.php:

```
require "core/php/engine.php";

 class SpellCheckButton extends SpellCheckInstance{
    public $CheckInSitu = false;
    public $WindowMode = "modal";  
    public $Class = "";
    public $Style = "";
    public $Image = "";
    public $ImageRollOver = "";
    public $Text = "";
```

Do I need to create a class inside my App\Http\Controllers or do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Have you put `namespace App` at the top

Comment: Can you show us your `/phpspellcheck/include.php` file?

Comment: it is a class from here : https://www.phpspellcheck.com/

Comment: When I read again, the easiest way seems to use `new \SpellCheckButton` (with a \ before it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your class in laravel. Following way to use class in the controller.

For example, your class inside `App\Classes`.

In Controller,

```
use App\Classes\Yourclass;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a `packages` folder in the root and add the package to another directory inside that folder. Suppose the path will be `packages/phpspellcheck`.
2. Tell composer to autoload the package by adding

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "PhpSpellCheck\\":"/packages/phpspellcheck/include.php"
    }
  }
}
```

to your `composer.json` file.

3. run `composer dumpautoload` to make composer generate a new `autoload.php` file, including the class you've added.

Then you can access the class as `PhpSpellCheck`.

The other methods are explained well here: https://codingexplained.com/coding/php/composer-autoloading-third-party-libraries-without-namespaces

Answer (score 0):

If you have created file inside `App` then you should put `namespace App` at the top of the page.

```
namespace App;
```

Namespace is the concept of PHP which is uses for creating files in namespace (or file in a folder which are written for same purpose)  and use it in a easy way instead of call using full path.